# PC doesn't boot into BIOS but Windows

Tags: windows-10, bios, uefi, firmware

I'm using Win10 and I'm not able to boot into BIOS, nor by hitting F2 or DEL while booting neither with the Windows 10 option: "Recovery / Advanced Setup / Troubleshoot / Advanced options / UEFI Firmware Settings "(this just boots the system back into Win10).

I'm using an ASUS PRIME B550-PLUS Mainboard with the newest Firmware (Version 1401).
"Turn on fast startup" in Windows is disabled, but this was also tested with fast startup "on".

HW/ SW:
CPU: Ryzen 7 5800x
MB: ASUS PRIME B550-PLUS
M2: Kingston A2000 1TB
OS: Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 1):

Are you by any chance using a DP to HDMI adapter and is it possible that the system does actually boot into BIOS, just without video? When booting, do you see the ASUS logo, post screen etc.? If this is the fact, switching to VGA or not using an adapter should do the trick.

Comment: I checked it with another monitor (HDMI) and I was able to access BIOS. But for me, this is still is really confusing. If I boot BIOS via Windows, it works with the monitor connected to HDMI. But when I reconnect my DP monitor it still boots into Windows from the "Windows boot into BIOS option". I'm not pressing any key or something in both cases. Why is it rushing through the Bios with one monitor but not the other (again: after hitting recovery option in windows both times)?

Comment: I cann't say why that behavior occurs, I've just seen this weird behavior - not showing BIOS, Post screens etc. sometimes depending on used video output - with several motherboards now, but mostly some more obscure OEM MBs.... Is there an option to select default video output in your BIOS? Have you tried resetting all BIOS settings as well as upgrading your MB to the latest available firmware?

Answer (score 0):

Open the computer and disconnect the SATA SSD or HDD (or remove the NVMe SSD if you are booting from that).

Without a boot-device you should get the option for the BIOS no matter what.

Comment: That was my last option :) 
My question is, what should I change (in bios) to get access next time. I don't want to disconnect the M2 each time I want to access the bios.

Comment: There is no setting to prevent you from getting the Bios. What usually happens with modern systems is that Bios init is so fast that it is faster than the startup time of the USB keyboard, meaning you can't press a key fast enough to activate the bios. Activating the UEFI boot via Windows should always work though. I've heard (never seen myself) that active CSM (or Legacy mode) in the UEFI Bios may interfere with this, so I would try with CSM off.